# Conectar tabla Microsoft Sql server en Azure Data Studio (MacOS) con Java

Tags: java, sql, azure, data, studio

Estoy intentando conectar una base de datos local para trabajar con la base de datos desde Java.
¿Saben como podría hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado intentando hacerlo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]